# replace some spaces with underscores in linux

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file that looks like this:

```
some text some text some text.
some other text. and others.
text text text ![Screenshot 2020-05-29 at 4.14.08 pm](./images/Screenshot 2020-05-29 at 4.14.08 pm.png)
![Screenshot 2020-05-29 at 4.04.08 pm](./images/Screenshot 2020-05-29 at 4.04.08 pm.png)
Some other text.
![Screenshot 2020-05-29 at 4.04.09 pm](./images/Screenshot 2020-05-29 at 4.04.09 pm.png) text text text
text text text ![Screenshot 2020-06-29 at 4.04.09 pm](./images/Screenshot 2020-06-29 at 4.04.09 pm.png) text text text
```

I want to replace the space with underscore in Screenshot names so that it becomes:

```
some text some text some text.
some other text. and others.
text text text ![Screenshot_2020-05-29_at_4.14.08_pm](./images/Screenshot_2020-05-29_at_4.14.08_pm.png)
![Screenshot_2020-05-29_at_4.04.08_pm](./images/Screenshot_2020-05-29_at_4.04.08_pm.png)
some other text.
![Screenshot_2020-05-29_at_4.04.09_pm](./images/Screenshot_2020-05-29_at_4.04.09_pm.png) text text text
text text text ![Screenshot_2020-06-29_at_4.04.09_pm](./images/Screenshot_2020-06-29_at_4.04.09_pm.png) text text text
```

Can **sed** do this?

If I use `sed -e "s/ /_/g"`, then all spaces, not just those in Screenshot file names, would be changed. I don't want to replace spaces in other text.

Thanks to anyone that could help out!

Comment: Try: `sed '/^!\[Screenshot /s/ /_/g' file`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your sample data and your comment you may use this `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/(?:\[Screenshot|(?!^)\G[^] ]+)\K (?=[^]]*])|(?:\([^) ]*Screenshot|(?!^)\G[^) ]+)\K (?=[^)]*\))/_/g' file
```

```
some text some text some text.
some other text. and others.
text text text ![Screenshot_2020-05-29_at_4.14.08_pm](./images/Screenshot_2020-05-29_at_4.14.08_pm.png)
![Screenshot_2020-05-29_at_4.04.08_pm](./images/Screenshot_2020-05-29_at_4.04.08_pm.png)
Some other text.
![Screenshot_2020-05-29_at_4.04.09_pm](./images/Screenshot_2020-05-29_at_4.04.09_pm.png) text text text
text text text ![Screenshot_2020-06-29_at_4.04.09_pm](./images/Screenshot_2020-06-29_at_4.04.09_pm.png) text text text
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FKTdf3/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `!\[Screenshot`: Match text `![ScreenShot`
  - `|`: OR
  - `(?!^)\G`: `\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or line start. `(?!^)` ensures `\G` doesn't match at line start.
  - `[^] ]+`: Match 1 or more of any character that is not space or `]`
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `\K`: Reset Match Info
- `(?=[^]]*])`: Lookahead to ensure we have a `]` ahead of us
- `|(?:\([^) ]*Screenshot|(?!^)\G[^) ]+)\K (?=[^)]*\))`: Do same for `(.*Screenshot.*.)` string

Comment: and what if I have lines like this:
text text ![Screenshot 2020-05-29 at 4.04.08 pm](./images/Screenshot 2020-05-29 at 4.04.08 pm.png)
or
![Screenshot 2020-05-29 at 4.04.08 pm](./images/Screenshot 2020-05-29 at 4.04.08 pm.png) text text text
meaning.. the line contains the pattern, as well as some other text. I don't want space in the nearby text to be replaced with underscore.

Comment: yes. but the filename may be at the start of a line, or in the middle, or at the ending part of a line. And if possible, can we use sed rather than perl?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data showing all these cases. It may not be possible for `sed` though

Comment: I have tested same `perl` command on given regex and works perfectly fine. Unfortunately `sed` cannot handle this complex processing.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^!\[Screenshot /y/ /_/' file
```

The `y` command is seds translate command similiar to the `tr` command line command.

If there is text before the text you want spaces underlined to remain with spaces in it, use this:

```
sed '/^!\[Screenshot /{s//\n&;h;y/_/ /;H;g;s/\n.*\n//}' file
```

This cuts the line in two, copies, amends and joins back the two parts, with the back half amended.

Comment: Hi. The ```Screenshot``` filename doesn't always stand alone, it may have text before it in the same line, or/and text after it in the same line. I want nearby text to remain same, and only replace spaces within ```![Screenshot_2020-05-29_at_4.04.08_pm](./images/Screenshot_2020-05-29_at_4.04.08_pm.png)```. How can we tackle it?

Comment: @jasminewu229 study the 2nd solution. How would you amend the front half of a line? If the line were split into 3, how would you replace just the 2nd piece? I feel your pain, but pain is a necessary part of the learning process.

Answer (score 0):

When the screenshot string continues until the first `)` or `]`, first put each screenshot string on a seperate line:

```
tr "\n" "\r" < "${file}" | sed -r 's/Screenshot|\]|\)/\n&/g' | 
   sed -r '/Screenshot/ s/ /_/g'  | tr -d '\n' | tr '\r' '\n'
```